# How to trigger a function app queue function after specific time interval after the queue receives a message

Tags: c#, azure, timer, azure-functions, azureservicebus

What I want is to place a message on something like a queue which has a trigger [Can be a ***function app trigger***] which is triggered some specified time after the message is received and not immediately as the **Service Bus Queue Trigger** currently works.

I do not want to implement waits within the function app during proccessing since this is expensive.

**Problem Description:**
I have a system composed of two function apps and 1 service bus queue.
The **first function app** has a **http trigger** that receives a http request transaction, validates it and sends the transaction message to the processing queue.

The **second function app** is a queue listener that receives the message from the second queue, calls an external API for a resource. I have to keep checking for the API to check my transaction status. This makes me to run a while loop within the request which keeps sleeping the thread for 5 seconds after which, I check for the status. I do not terminate the function app in order to keep making the requests. This becomes costly since the function apps are billed per time taken during request execution.

The challenge with a **service bus queue function app queue trigger** is that it won't wait to trigger the listener function to call the external API to check for the status of the transaction after 5 seconds from the time the message arrives at the queue. I want to trigger the function app queue listener 5 seconds after the message has been received by the queue. Not immediately it is received.

Is there (not necessarily a service bus queue) a service / component / Azure product/ **solution** that can help me achieve this?

Any extra advise / information is highly welcome

***Thank you***

Comment: When you send the message to the queue, you can specify the `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc`. So you can delay message processing.

Comment: Let me try that. Thanks for the tip in advance

Comment: You will want to check CloudQueueMessage visibility. An example is shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658494/azure-storage-queue-message-show-at-specific-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure storage queue message (show at specific time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658494/azure-storage-queue-message-show-at-specific-time)